# Sharepoint 2013 - Contributers unable to add pictures/upload documents to discussion board posts

Tags: permissions, file-upload, discussion-board, attachments

I've recently set up a SharePoint 2013 site internally as a small intranet for our staff.

I've set up a discussion board and managed to assign permissions so that all users are contributors and my account (the owner of the SP site) has full access.

I am able to post in the discussion board fine and attach documents and attach pictures to posts, however everyone else is unable to do any form of attachments (be it pictures or upload document attachments) to their posts, it just throws back an error.

I'd rather not have to up their permission level as I only want them to be contributors, I don't want them to have access to edit the lists etc and make any advanced changes or admin access, I want them to have purely standard user access to post, reply and attach pics etc.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Within the error message should be a correlation id. Take this ID and search the ULS logs on the server, usually in c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\15\logs. That should match to an actual error message. If you can't find one, crank up diagnostic logging in Central Admin - Monitoring - Configure Diagnostic Logging and set All Categories to Verbose.

Comment: Ive searched the log file at the time of the error and there are numerous entries for the correlation ID it showed.  Ive no idea what any of it means though!?

Comment: yeah, you'll see a trail for the id, towards the end of them you should see an error or exception.